# Why does the CustomScrollView not work in android emulator?

Tags: flutter

**By using Customscrollview and Slivers widgets everything shows well on the screen but when I try to scroll up and down there is no silver effect or any animation, the screen does not even scroll up and down**

I am using Flutter beta version with Android emulator 19~

link https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html

these are the two .dart files I am using right now:

main.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:p1/home.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter facebook UI',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: HomeScreen(),
        );
     

 }
}
```

home.dart

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        
        class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  SliverAppBar(
                    brightness: Brightness.light,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    title: Text(
                      'welcome',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 28.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        letterSpacing: -1.2,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

**Everything shows well on the screen but when I try to scroll up and down there is no silver effect or any animation, the screen does not even scroll up and down, any help?**

Comment: Could you add the details what you mean by "not work". Post the error you see or the expected behavior.

Comment: everything shows well on the screen but when I try to scroll up and down there is no silver effect or any animation

Comment: you need to add some other slivers below `SliverAppBar`, like `SliverList` for example

Comment: It says that ` A CustomScrollView lets you supply slivers directly to create various scrolling effects, such as lists, grids, and expanding headers. For example, to create a scroll view that contains an expanding app bar followed by a list and a grid, use a list of three slivers: SliverAppBar, SliverList, and SliverGrid. ` so nothing works even if I add sliverlist

Comment: post your updated code then

Comment: It worked after I changed the entire CustomScrollView() with the code here on the flutter site: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html 

why mine does not work? the code on the flutter site does not have any SliverList()

Comment: but it has `SliverGrid`? it does not matter what sliver you add, what matters: it has to be tall enough to be scrolled

Comment: You're right, if the content is not tall it doesn't scroll. thx

Comment: sure, your welcome